# JBoss-7 deployment failed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am trying to deploy a .war file on Jboss-7.1.1 and getting the following error in stacktrace. I have searched about it on web but not sure the cause of this exception

```
23:01:20,483 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry p6psy.jar in "/D:/development_environment/servers/Final_jboss/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/SSOAdminTool.war/WEB-INF/lib/xapool.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
23:01:20,800 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001:     Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SSOAdminTool.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SSOAdminTool.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SSOAdminTool.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_18]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_18]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_18]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter from [Module "deployment.SSOAdminTool.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
... 7 more
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty straightforward - *Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter*.

Comment: I have had running this fine on Jboss-4.2. I included proper jars for that in my classpath.

Comment: If required jar is in your WAR/WEB-INF/lib OR in {JBOSS_HOME}/Modules, then only it will load jars. make sure jars are in lib.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing out some jars in my WEB-INF/lib. Finally solved the issue. Thanks again